# Laravel 4.2 error pages have disappeared

Tags: laravel

Yesterday I've installed the latest version of Laravel (v4.2.1) and ever since, it just replaces my error screens (for debugging) by blank screens...

Things I've done:

- Set "'debug' => true" in config/app.php
- Give read and write permission to app/storage by executing "chmod -R 777" (did this a few thousand times already)
- Reinstall the framework

Whenever I intentionally introduce a syntax error in routes.php, it just shows a blank page. The syntax error-message IS however written to the log file (app/storage/logs/laravel.log).

If I install an earlier version of Laravel (such as 4.1.8), everything works fine, so I think its related to this new version, but I just can't figure out what's causing this ultra annoying behaviour.

Comment: There is an issue with the current error reporting package: whoops. Specifically, it is causing some breaking issues in the Laravel Framework. Until this is resolved, whoops error reporting will not be available.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4378

Comment: UPDATE: As of Laravel 4.2.3, whoops has been added back. Make sure you do a `composer update --prefer-dist`. The styling is not the same as previous version, but you do have the familiar symfony stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now. For some strange reason, whenever I installed a new copy using the laravel.phar file from the official website (`php laravel new`), the post-install scripts inside the composer.json didn't run after the installation.

When I ran these myself (`php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize`) , everything worked again. Also, whenever I install Laravel via composer (`php composer create-project laravel/laravel`) instead of via the laravel.phar file, these post-install scripts DID run.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your local environment here: `bootstrap/start.php:29`. You open up terminal / command prompt and type in `hostname`. Laravel by default decides the environment by hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you've upgraded to 4.2 entirely correctly, you will have an environment specific app.php config file, probably in `app/config/local/app.php`. See what the value of `debug` is in there.

Comment: Sadly, there it also says "'debug' => true" (inside app/config/local/app.php). I'm absolutely clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same thing.  You have to change the config/app file.  Out of the box the config/local/app.php file has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers didn't work for you, you may want to check the config files that you might have changed and start debugging from there.

In my case, the above solutions didn't work for me because the root cause of my problem was changing the timezone in config/app.php file (from laravel default UTC I changed it to EST5EDT). For some reason the timezone setting change prevents laravel from logging the errors in storage folder and I am getting blank screen (no whoops! error message). I changed the timezone to America/New_York instead and the error logs are working again.

Hope this helps.